# Can't add Schedule task in Win XP, limited user

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I've built a program in C# Windows Forms, now on the first load up it tries to create scheduled tasks. If it raises an exception and it's in main computer then this is the first time the softwere loads (you can intall this program on many computers but one computer is the main with the scheduled tasks).

I've tried this program on many computers and it worked perfectly (XP-SP1/2, Vista-SP1/2, Win7), now when I try to install it on a limited user (on Win XP Pro SP2) it tries to create the scheduled tasks. I get an Argument Null Reference and when I enter the admin user, it installs the scheduled task on the admin user and won't run if the limited user is logged in (which is 99.9% of the time) .Why do I get this exception? I've looked for hours on the code searching for the reason of this exception but I can't find it!

Thanks a lot!

Amit

```
MainOrSec = true;
```

User and Pass are public variables whice return from FirstTimeUp.

```
private bool CreateNoExit()
        {
            try
            {
                RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser;
                key = key.OpenSubKey("Crm");
                MainOrSec = Convert.ToBoolean(AESIMP.Decrypt((string)key.GetValue(AESIMP.Encrypt("MorS"))));
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                MainOrSec = true;
            }
            if (MainOrSec)
            {
                ScheduledTasks sc = new ScheduledTasks();
                Task task;
                try
                {
                    task = sc.CreateTask("NoExit");
                    FirstTimeUp f = new FirstTimeUp(this);
                    f.ShowDialog();
                }
                catch (ArgumentException)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!CreatT)
                    return false;
                task.ApplicationName = @"C:\Program Files\Triffon\Crm Setup
2.0.0002\noexit.exe";
                task.Comment = "Check For no exit on the database.";
                task.SetAccountInformation(User, Pass);
                task.IdleWaitMinutes = 10;
                task.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger(5, 0));
                try
                {
                    task.Save();
                    task.Close();
                    sc.Dispose();
                }
                catch (COMException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: since i told you it worked on every system but this limited user condition though you won't need that - cause i've a problem with permission or some code i've missed that dealing with permissions. i'll edit the question and add the code.

Comment: And which line of code triggers the exception?  For bonus points, print the values of each variable used in that line, or inspect them with the debugger.  You'll likely find that you're trying to dereference a null.

Comment: that what make me angry! putted all over the code "try-catch" with a messagebox and no function from this code or other classes it uses, raise this exception

Comment: look , it worked on all of computer, my code does not raise it! if it does then the what you say that the code go crazy on this specific computer?! installed the software with same parameter on my computer and it works fine. that the built in function of creating the scheduled tasks does it, probably because of permissions, thought someone know this and solved it..

Comment: The title of your question has nothing to do with the problem. The code isn't managing scheduled tasks, you just have a piece of code that doesn't work in some user contexts.

Comment: and that because ? because i can't add any scheduled task because(!) the user does not have permissions, then the code is right! it's just missing something that dealing with permissions. really thank you for trying help me but a least stop mark me down or say wrong thing because you don't know the answer...

Comment: Your code is triggering an exception. Just because it's not happening on every computer doesn't make this any less true. Post the exception's stack trace, and maybe we'll be able to help you. And drop the attitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so if you get an exception, the best thing to do is to run your program under Visual Studio's debugger so you can see exactly where the exception is called. Here, <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-E</kbd> is your friend: turn on the checkbox in the "Thrown" column next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" and you'll break to the debugger no matter what.

If you are testing your application on a user's computer without Visual Studio then you have some other options. One (if you're using Pro and above) is to run the [Remote Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) on the remote PC. Then you can attach to the running program and see the exception.

If you don't have Pro, or can't easily use the remote debugger, then it is definitely worth using a decent logging framework like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) to make sure that all exceptions are caught, trapped, and written to a log file. Frankly no production application should be released until this is done.

When you've done this, take a careful look at the exception trace to see where the problem is caused. I'd be willing to bet that that `ScheduledTasks` class is throwing an exception somewhere that you're not expecting.

Finally, you'll be getting downvotes because the culture here is "we'll help if you let us know everything we need to know to help." There's been a couple of requests in the comments for the full stack trace, which hasn't appeared, so people here will consider that rude, I'm afraid.

Comment: you are right, didn't mean to sound that way but you really need to see me seating on a seat writing this softwere to a buissnes and then i get this exception where thay have 30 computers with a limited user...finally i found a solution, you install the task with admin username and password and then give ntfs permissions to those task...it's solved it out...took me hours to write those nfts permissions, but at lease it's working :)  thanks for the info about Remote debugger. never heard of it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to figure this out without a stack trace, but there is a suspicious line of code.

According to MSDN `RegistryKey.GetValue()` returns:

> The value associated with name, or a
>   null reference (Nothing in Visual
>   Basic) if name is not found.

Here you pass the result of that function directly to another function:

```
MainOrSec = Convert.ToBoolean(AESIMP.Decrypt((string)key.GetValue(AESIMP.Encrypt("MorS"))));
```

Try to call it in a few steps instead, checking for null where needed:

```
string s = key.GetValue(AESIMP.Encrypt("MorS")) as string;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    MainOrSec = Convert.ToBoolean(AESIMP.Decrypt(s));
else
    MainOrSec = true;
```

Comment: Thanks. but that why i putted it in "try-catch", on first load it triggers the null exception and then it enters the Configuration Manger of the program, there i solve the exception for next load...the problem is more about permission but thanks for trying help me